# conan protobuf compilation complains about undefined reference

Tags: conan

While trying to setup `protobuf/3.9.1`, I am getting some errors in the final linking stage of my binary.

One of the errors is as follows:

```
error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>::data() const'
```

My `conanfile.py` looks like this:

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class ConanSetup(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "arch", "build_type"
    requires = ("boost/1.71.0@conan/stable", "TBB/2019_U9@conan/stable",
                "protobuf/3.9.1", "protoc_installer/3.9.1@bincrafters/stable")
    generators = "cmake"
```

Similarly, `profile.txt` is as follows:

```
[settings]
os=Linux
os.distro=Fedora
os_build=Linux
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.cppstd=gnu20

[options]
boost:extra_b2_flags="cxxflags=-flto -ffat-lto-objects" "linkflags=-flto -ffat-lto-objects"
boost:fPIC=False
boost:without_test=True
TBB:shared=False
protobuf:shared=True  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ======== Also tried with False
```

Just in case you are interested, here's the error in full:

```
/opt/gcc91/bin/g++  -g  -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--as-needed -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,-rpath='/opt/gcc91/lib64'     -fno-lto ccgh/aqua/src/CMakeFiles/aqua.dir/main.cc.o  -o ccgh/aqua/src/aquaD -L~/.conan/data/boost/1.71.0/conan/stable/package/767bc0c23078a99d05bef69ea167ec13a5d69b0f/lib  -L~/.conan/data/TBB/2019_U9/conan/stable/package/0e97b647214fb55bba1058259083f01b428a3f88/lib  -L~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/_/_/package/b8ab1d67667e2949b68c0ac0e86f545e14b80e34/lib  -L~/.conan/data/protoc_installer/3.9.1/bincrafters/stable/package/c0c1ef10e3d0ded44179e28b669d6aed0277ca6a/lib  -L~/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/0a12e20d4cbf80053ba25ce1d9d9fd217d453f7c/lib  -L~/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/conan/stable/package/dba695cfd0357a6ad5f9a4c70ee2856a6f0427d7/lib -Wl,-rpath,~/.conan/data/boost/1.71.0/conan/stable/package/767bc0c23078a99d05bef69ea167ec13a5d69b0f/lib:~/.conan/data/TBB/2019_U9/conan/stable/package/0e97b647214fb55bba1058259083f01b428a3f88/lib:~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/_/_/package/b8ab1d67667e2949b68c0ac0e86f545e14b80e34/lib:~/.conan/data/protoc_installer/3.9.1/bincrafters/stable/package/c0c1ef10e3d0ded44179e28b669d6aed0277ca6a/lib:~/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/0a12e20d4cbf80053ba25ce1d9d9fd217d453f7c/lib:~/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.8/conan/stable/package/dba695cfd0357a6ad5f9a4c70ee2856a6f0427d7/lib:~/code/p/higgs4/vendor/unix/linux-x86_64/solace-ccsmp-7.0.0.85/solclient/lib: -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined ccgh/aqua/src/libaquacoreD.a -lboost_wave -lboost_container -lboost_contract -lboost_exception -lboost_graph -lboost_iostreams -lboost_locale -lboost_log -lboost_program_options -lboost_random -lboost_regex -lboost_serialization -lboost_wserialization -lboost_coroutine -lboost_fiber -lboost_context -lboost_timer -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_atomic -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_type_erasure -lboost_log_setup -lboost_math_c99 -lboost_math_c99f -lboost_math_c99l -lboost_math_tr1 -lboost_math_tr1f -lboost_math_tr1l -lboost_stacktrace_addr2line -lboost_stacktrace_basic -lboost_stacktrace_noop -ltbb -lprotoc protobuf/libprotobufD.a -lpthread -lz -lbz2 ccgh/libbobapi2/src/libbobapi2D.a ccgh/libcmeapi/src/libcmeapiD.a ccgh/libfix/src/libfixD.a ccgh/libems/src/libemsD.a ccgh/libitchapi/src/libitchapiD.a ccgh/libom/src/libomD.a ccgh/libflexapi/src/libflexapiD.a ccgh/librefdata/src/librefdataD.a ccgh/ext/cctz/cctz/libcctzD.a ccgh/libfmdapi/src/libfmdapiD.a ccgh/libmktapi/src/libmktapiD.a ccgh/libcore/src/libcoreD.a -lboost_wave -lboost_container -lboost_contract -lboost_exception -lboost_graph -lboost_iostreams -lboost_locale -lboost_log -lboost_program_options -lboost_random -lboost_regex -lboost_serialization -lboost_wserialization -lboost_coroutine -lboost_fiber -lboost_context -lboost_timer -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono -lboost_date_time -lboost_atomic -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_type_erasure -lboost_log_setup -lboost_math_c99-lboost_math_c99f -lboost_math_c99l -lboost_math_tr1 -lboost_math_tr1f -lboost_math_tr1l -lboost_stacktrace_addr2line -lboost_stacktrace_basic -lboost_stacktrace_noop -ltbb -lprotoc protobuf/libprotobufD.a -lpthread -lz -lbz2 ccgh/ext/libcassandra/libcassandra-2.8.0/libcassandra_libD.a ccgh/ext/libcassandra/libuv-1.9.1/libuvD.a /usr/lib64/libssl.so /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so ccgh/ext/openonload/libciulD.a ccgh/ext/dfpml/libdfpmlD.a ccgh/ext/farmhash/libfarmhashD.a ccgh/ext/flatbuffers/libflatbuffersD.a ccgh/ext/fmtlib/libfmtlibD.a ../../vendor/unix/linux-x86_64/solace-ccsmp-7.0.0.85/solclient/lib/libsolclient.so ccgh/ext/sqlite3/libsqliteD.a -lpthread -lrt -latomic ccgh/ext/google/bigquery/libgoogle_bigquery_apiD.a ccgh/ext/google/googleapis/googleapis/client/libgoogleapis_jsoncppD.a ccgh/ext/google/googleapis/googleapis/client/libgoogleapis_jsonD.a ccgh/ext/google/googleapis/googleapis/client/libgoogleapis_utilsD.a ccgh/ext/google/googleapis/libgoogleapis_internalD.a ccgh/ext/glog/libglogd.a ccgh/ext/google/jsoncpp/src/lib_json/libjsoncppD.a -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -ldl && :

~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/_/_/package/b8ab1d67667e2949b68c0ac0e86f545e14b80e34/include/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.h:196: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::StringPiece::LogFatalSizeTooBig(unsigned long, char const*)'

ccgh/libcore/src/gng/core/symbology/sym.pb.h:177: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*)'
../../ccgh/libcore/src/gng/util/make_pb.h:25: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::util::JsonStringToMessage(google::protobuf::StringPiece, google::protobuf::Message*, google::protobuf::util::JsonParseOptions const&)'
../../ccgh/libcore/src/gng/util/make_pb.h:29: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::util::Status::ToString[abi:cxx11]() const'

~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/_/_/package/b8ab1d67667e2949b68c0ac0e86f545e14b80e34/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:378: error: undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage&)'
~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/_/_/package/b8ab1d67667e2949b68c0ac0e86f545e14b80e34/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:378: error: undefined reference to 'google::proto
buf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
```

Comment: what version of conan are you running?

Comment: I am using `v1.22`. I have also tried it on `1.21.1`

Comment: On ubuntu I have seen strange behaviour of overriding default `compiler.libcxx`, could you, please double check if that is not happening here?

Comment: Looks like it is using the correct stdlib: ` -- Conan: C++ stdlib: libstdc++11`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use `protobuf/3.9.1@bincrafters/stable` instead. The problem is there is no  good way for porting protoc to Conan Center Index, because when crossbuild it can't export a Find cmake file for protoc installer.

Also, the project protobuf is built all together by default. It has been separated the protoc (bin) from the libprotobuf, due the cross-building scenario, when the library is provided to a specific architecture (e.g. armv8), but protoc runs on your host (x86_64).

Comment: Damn, I should have written - I had the exact same problem with `protobuf/3.9.1@bincrafters/stable` too. That was my first attempt, then tried this Conan Center Index.

Comment: Just tried it again with the same results: https://pastebin.com/McKvXBvr

Comment: Did you try building from sources? `conan install protobuf/3.9.1@bincrafters/stable --build protobuf` I believe it can be related to your distro. All packages are built on Ubuntu, which may vary the ABI compatibility

Comment: BTW I strong recommend open an issue to Bincrafters in this case: https://github.com/bincrafters/community/issues, where you will find more support (due authors presence)

Comment: Thanks. I did so at https://github.com/bincrafters/community/issues/1123. 
Btw, to answer your question, I do build it locally as I use a custom GCC. That means everything has to be built. Perhaps that has something to do with the linking issues.